# Adding same text to all files of the directory

Tags: perl, file

I have one folder. There are 32 files and 3 directories in that folder. I want to add some lines of text on each file at top. How can I do that?

Comment: `opendir` and `readdir` should help you read your recursive directory structure.  You can use file tests like `-d` to find whether or not the file you looked at is a directory.  Once you've found a real file, one way to add text at the top is to read it in, close it, open it for output, write your top text, and then write the rest of the file out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) to find the files. Use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File) and [unshift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html) to add lines to the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

TLP already told you some hints how to solve the Problem. But there is always more then one way to do it. Instead of File::Find and Tie::File i would use some more "modern" modules. In these full example i use Path::Class::Rule with an iterative interface instead of an recursive interface that i like more.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use open ':std';
use Path::Class;
use Path::Class::Rule;

my $rule = Path::Class::Rule->new->file;
my $iter = $rule->iter(dir('test'));

while ( my $file = $iter->() ) {
    print $file->stringify, "\n";
    add_line_to_file($file, "Sid was here.\n");
}

# 1: Path::Class::File Object
# 2: The Line
sub add_line_to_file {
    my ( $file, $line ) = @_;

    # Open File - return IO::File object
    my $fh = $file->open('>>') or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";
    # Seek to end
    $fh->seek(0, 2);
    # Add line
    $fh->print($line);
    $fh->close;

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^/my text\n/' * */*
```

Please try this on copy of your directory to make sure it does what you want.

Comment: This will add `my text` to all the lines in every file. Rather, the OP wants to add it only once at the top. `perl -pi -e '$.==1 and s/^/my text\n/' <file>` does the job. But it should be run with only one file at a time.

Comment: @Gowtham Thanks for correction. I tested on single line files and missed the problem that would happen with multiple lines.

Comment: @AKJ `perl -0777 -pi.bak -we '$_ = "foobar\n$_"'`? Slurp mode fixes it.

Comment: @Gowtham You can reset `$.` with `close ARGV if eof`. That way, you can use multiple files.

Comment: @TLP I did not know that $. can be assigned to. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @gow Not assigned to. Reset. Set back to default.